# Are "do I need first part to understand second" questions good thing?

Tags: discussion

I asked two questions, already asking if I need to watch the first part of the movie to understand the second (here: [1](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/95878/do-i-need-to-see-the-incredibles-to-understand-incredibles-2), [2](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/106042/how-much-is-original-jumanji-important-to-the-sequel)).

I think these questions can be really beneficial. Both of mine received a positive score, and I got the information I needed.

**BUT**
Today I again run to the same situation. I again have a movie, and I would like to watch only the third part, without watching first and second.
But I am not sure if this type of question is really good for the site. There are tons of potential questions like this (about every movie that has at least two parts).
It can potentially bloat and spam the site because they're really easy to ask.

**Should we ask them?

If so, should we have some rules about them?**

Answer (score 2):

Frankly, I'm not a big fan of them. To me they seem pointless when it involves one or two movies: either watch them or don't, it's at most a couple of hours you lose. It's a different thing when it comes to an elaborate franchise with dozens of films and/or TV shows etc., which would require a substantial investment of time and effort.